# Remove 'Details' button from ProgressMonitorJobsDialog JFace

Tags: eclipse, dialog, jface, rcp, jobs

I am trying to remove the 'Details' button from the following ProgressMonitorJobsDialog:

[image: JFace Dialog with progress bar]

I am running a org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job that opens the default Dialog. I have seen examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957562/swt-tweaking-my-progressmonitordialog) of disabling the Cancel button, but I need to remove the third one and extending the default ProgressMonitorJobsDialog won't help, since it is invoked by the default UIJob class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This dialog is usually `ProgressMonitorFocusJobDialog` displayed by `ProgressManager`. It isn't really possible to change the dialog without using internal APIs.

Instead of a `Job` you could use an `IRunnableWithProgress` and use `ProgressMonitorDialog` to run it. This dialog does not have the Details section.